# Is there a word to describe the smell of death?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there anything else that smells like something dead to even compare the "death smell" to?

The smell of death is called ___

Death smells like ___

Comment: Are you thinking of this [flower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrion_flower)?

Comment: Could you furnish an example sentence with a blank in it please, as the tag info requests, in order that we can be sure about what you're asking for?

Comment: Never heard of that thing—sure looks disgusting!

Comment: _Durian_ comes to mind.

Comment: Not sure. Does death have a smell? What does it smell like? Are you talking about the smell of a (human) corpse decomposing?

Comment: Any corpse decomposing.

Comment: You'd actually have some luck Googling "what does death smell like" but I think there's a difference between the name of the chemicals, as you answered yourself, and what the smell is "like".  I've heard it described as "sickly sweet", "putrid", "unmistakenly the smell of death" or "rotting meat".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind.  I *think* I found it.  Not sure if this is the actual name of the smell though.

> [**Cadaverine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadaverine) - a foul-smelling diamine compound produced by the
>   putrefaction of animal tissue.
>
> [**Putrescine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putrescine) - a foul-smelling organic chemical compound that is related to cadaverine; both are produced by the breakdown of amino
>   acids in living and dead organisms and both are toxic in large doses

(Source: Wikipedia)

Comment: Hello, Roy. Nice find. I have added the source in your answer. Please include the sources in all your future answers. :)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't think I needed the source for those definitions though because they are linked through the words.

Comment: Linking is important. But it's also important to mention the source by name. It's written clearly in the [help]. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing :)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more common term would be **miasma**, which can also be used metaphorically.

> 1. noxious exhalations from putrescent organic matter; poisonous effluvia or germs polluting the atmosphere.
> 2. a dangerous, foreboding, or deathlike influence or atmosphere.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/miasma